# My VB.NET Windows Service Not Starting with UAC Enabled

Tags: vb.net, service

I am new to VS.NET (but VB6 veteran).  I'm writing a VB.NET (2010) app that has both a GUI and a background Windows Service.  My service was created following all the typical "how-to" articles.

My Windows Service installs just fine using installutil and VS command prompt, but I can't get the service to actually start without turning UAC off.  If UAC is left on, I get the dreaded "Error 740:  The requested operation requires elevation".

HUH???

This service installs as LocalSystem, the absolute highest priviledged access on any system, even higher than Admin.  Why on earth would further elevation be required?  Even editing manifest/config for elevation doesn't make this error go away, which makes this all seem very broken to me.

Clue:  Again, the service fires right up if UAC is disabled, which should NOT have to be required.

I have read Windows Service "how-to" articles and followed them to the best of my ability, and none of them ever mention this issue.  I obviously cannot force my users to turn UAC off, so there must be something I'm overlooking.

Really desperate for help on this one, my thanks to anyone who can assist!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an installer for your service, you can set the service to run under the LocalService account.  This will typically have the elevate privileges required.

Example:

```
yourProcessInstaller.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalService
yourProcessInstaller.UserName = Nothing
yourProcessInstaller.Password = Nothing
```

If that's not enough, you can prompt for the installing user to specify the credentials of the user it should run under:

```
yourProcessInstaller.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.User
yourProcessInstaller.UserName = Nothing
yourProcessInstaller.Password = Nothing
```

Note that in the latter, your user will have to specify the computer name when entering the User it should run under.

Example: MyComputerName\MyUserName

Comment: In the properties for the installer, I did in fact set it to LocalService.  It installs fine, and I use the installutil in the VStudio command prompt to do it.  No problems there.  Also edited manifest/config for elevated (correct for a service?)  I do not want the user to have to enter their own creds to get it working, though they can always make changes to the service if they choose.  I just want it running as LocalService without the user having to go through any hassles.  Does your hardcode above work differently than using the same clickable selection choices in the IDE?

Comment: If I select LocalService, do I still have to make the changes to manifest/config?  Or is elevation automatically handled for a service in .NET when it's set to LocalService?  I must get this solved, as I cannot force my users to disable UAC.